# Laravel Blade, global meta description and different meta description for subpage

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-blade, meta-tags

I have a index.blade with all the necessary meta tags in the header, lets take the description for example:

```
<meta name="description" content="This is the description">
```

This is my current index file

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@yield('site_title')</title>
    @yield('head_content')

    <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
    ...
</head>
```

Now, for a specific subpage (/page), I would like to have a different description, this is what I have:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('head_content')

<meta name="description" content="This is a different description">

@endsection
```

This unfortunately adds both meta description on the final html subpage. Is there a way to have a different meta descriptions for a single subpage, but otherwise have the global description?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `@overwrite` instead of `@endsection` to ... overwrite the original content:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('head_content')
<meta name="description" content="This is a different description">
@overwrite
```

Edit: change your layout to use a section instead of `@yield`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@yield('site_title')</title>
    @section('head_content')
    <meta name="description" content="This is the description">
    @show
    ...
</head>
```

2nd Edit:
If you have multiple meta tags you could also use something like this in your layout:

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>@yield('site_title')</title>
    <meta name="description" content="@yield('meta_description', 'This is the description')">
    <meta name="keywords" content="@yield('meta_keywords', 'these,are,the,keywords')">
    ...
</head>
```

Then in your subpage you could use:

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('meta_description', 'A subpage description');
@section('meta_keywords', 'my,subpage,keywords');
```

Comment: Hey @brombeer, thank you for the quick answer. Unfortunately it still shows me both meta descriptions on the final subpage. I updated my answer with how my index file looks like if that helps. Thanks! :)

Comment: Since the `<meta>` element in your layout/index is not inside a `@section` it cannot be replaced and will always render. I updated my answer, see if it works when you change your index to use a section

Comment: Thank you for the update, that seems to work. So basically I have to put **all** my meta tags between `@section(head_content` and `@show` in the index file and then overwrite it in the subpages.

Comment: @Paranoia Not necessarily. I edited my answer with a 2nd edit which uses `@yield` with a default value, see if that works for multiple meta elements

Comment: One question per "question" please. If your current question was solved by this answer please accept it so it can be marked as resolved. This should work the same way with OG properties. Try to implement one of these two ways with opengraph properties and if you have problems, please ask another question. Thanks and glad it works

Answer (score 1):

`@overwrite` is the same as `@endsection` but replaces existing content

```
@extends('layouts.app')
@section('head_content')
<meta name="description" content="This is a different description">
@overwrite
```

[DOCUMENTATION](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/templates)

Comment: Please mark as verified if its help for you Thank you @Paranoia

Comment: Hey @vikas, also thank you for the quick answer! Unfortunately it still shows me both meta descriptions on the final subpage. I updated my answer with how my index file looks like if that helps.